# Validation of data that 'closely resembles' a where clause

Tags: .net, regex, parsing, validation, where-clause

I am working on validation logic of user input to what is pretty close to a sql where clause.

On the page the user can select from a combination of dropdowns (where the '-' character represents a blank character in the final clause):

```
DropDown1   DropDown2       DropDown3   DropDown4   DropDown5  DropDown6

-           -               -           -           -          -
(           SomeCriteria    =           Value       )          AND
                            <>                                 OR
```

Unfortunately I don't have any hard requirements on how to validate this clause other than it should 'behave like a sql where clause' :(

A few that should pass validation

```
(Criteria = Value)
(criteria1 = Value1 OR Criteria2 <> value2)
(criteria1 = value1) AND (Criteria2 = value2)
(criteria1 = value1) OR (Criteria2 = value2 AND criteria3 = value3)
```

A few that should fail validation:

```
)Criteria = value) (first character is not  '(' )
(Criteria = value(  (last character is not  ')' )
((Criteria = value)  (# of '(' does not match # of ')' )

(Criteria = Value (AND Criteria1 = value1))  ( 'AND' and 'OR' should not be immediately preceded  or followed by a '('  or ')' character.
```

Any assistance on writing a regex to validate these selections would be truly appreciated.  After poking around I have seen others speak of a sql parser would that be a better solution for this 'restricted' where clause?

Comment: Is the user going to be inputing a custom Value and Criteria for each "row"? Or do they just select from a list of predefined values/criteria?

Comment: No regex can validate the balance of the brackets unless you add more constraints on to the problem

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you mean about needing brackets. You don't need regex here though.

Comment: How does the user specify a criteria? Because I really do not see the need for 7 dropdowns, would it not be smarter with just 1 dropdown and an add button? That way it will be assembled bit by bit, and you can show it to the user? This also gives you the oportunity to prevent the user from inputing obvius illegal values (e.g. no close brackets before an open has been added).

Comment: @Kelrond you're right. Because how else would the user make a stmt like this: (A == B AND B != C OR (A == B OR (A == C)))  with 3 closing brackets at once..

Comment: Updated my code based on @Kelrond's question..

Comment: @Kelrond the criteria type is just loaded from our database as well as the values available for the criteria type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** For situations where the user needs to make a statement like: `(A == B AND B != C OR (A == B OR (A == C)))`,  Your solution will only work if you give the user more options in the left brackets dropdown and the right brackets dropdown lists. Left brackets dropdown should include these options: `'(', '((', '(((', '(((('` and you could cap it off at 4 left brackets in a row. Right brackets dropdown should look the same.

You could put your dropdowns inside a Repeater so that .Net will assign each dropdown a unique ID.

Validation code:

```
// this will keep track of left brackets that have not been closed
int numUnclosedLeftBrackets = 0;


// changing dropdown instance names for clarity
ddlLeftBracket == DropDown1;
ddlCriteria == DropDown2;
ddlConOperator == DropDown3;
ddlValue == DropDown4;
ddlRightBracket = DropDown5;
ddlExtension == DropDown6;

Boolean isValidStmt = false;
Boolean areValidBrackets = false;
Boolean addAnotherStmt = false;

// conditional operator dropdown cannot be blank
if(ddlConOperator.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
    if(ddlConOperator.SelectedValue == "=" && ddlCriteria.SelectedValue == ddlValue.SelectedValue)
        isValidStmt = true;
    if(ddlConOperator.SelectedValue == "<>" && ddlCriteria.SelectedValue != ddlValue.SelectedValue)
        isValidStmt = true;

    // check if both left and right brackets exist, or if both do not exist.
    if((ddlLeftBracket.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlRightBracket.SelectedIndex == 0) || 
               (ddlLeftBracket.SelectedIndex > 0 && ddlRightBracket.SelectedIndex > 0)) 
        areValidBrackets = true;

    // check if AND, or OR is attached
    if(ddlExtension.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        addAnotherStmt = true;

        // check if brackets need to be validated now that the where clause will continue on
        if(!areValidBrackets) 
        {
            // check if left bracket but no right bracket
            if(ddlLeftBracket.SelectedIndex > 0 && ddlRightBracket.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                areValidBrackets = true;
                numUnclosedLeftBrackets += ddlLeftBracket.SelectedIndex;
            }
            // check if right bracket but no left bracket
            if(ddlLeftBracket.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlRightBracket.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                // check if left bracket needs closing in a previous value/criteria row and make sure user is not trying to add more right closing brackets than allowed
                if(numUnclosedLeftBrackets > 0 && (numUnclosedLeftBrackets - ddlRightBracket.SelectedIndex) > -1)
                {
                    areValidBrackets = true;
                    numUnclosedLeftBrackets -= ddlRightBracket.SelectedIndex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Since the user has not selected AND or OR, check that there are no unclosed left brackets remaining
        if(numUnclosedLeftBrackets > 0)
            areValidBrackets = false;
    }
}
if(!areValidBrackets)
    // brackets not valid
else
    if(!isValidStmt)
        // not a valid statement
    else
        if(addAnotherStmt)
            // create a new row
        else
            // finished and valid - allow saving valid 'WHERE clause' string
```

You could make it so the most recent repeater row is enabled and all previous rows are disabled, forcing the user to remove each most recent row until the row they want to edit becomes enabled. This simplifies validation, b/c then you are only concerned with the most recent row, knowing that all previous rows were validated. When the most recent row is valid, it will be safe to run the entire string as an SQL WHERE clause.

**NOTE:** If you lock down previous rows like i suggested, then when the user deletes the most recent row you will have to check the value of `numUnclosedLeftBrackets` and this may require a slightly different approach, such as: storing the repeater row index for each row containing an unclosed left bracket.

Comment: This would work, but how could someone specify `(A && B)||(B || C)`?

Comment: Hi thanks for the responses, I will look into it and see if I can play around with it to fit my needs.

One minor thing to note is the results will be grid based and I will then rap up the final result and validate so a user could make a clause like

(
criteria = val
) AND
( criteria1 = val1)

I think your code will handle this except for the requirement that each line contain an operator...definetly not a big deal and I can edit and change.  Once again your help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks you.

Comment: @GartuanTezMaximus Please mark my answer as correct if I have helped you. I think I know what you mean by 'grid based' but consider using a Repeater. My proposed solution completely avoids having to traverse the entire result for a massive validation but, only if you only allow the user to edit the most current row and disable editing of all previous ones.

Comment: @BumbleB2na, I'm not sure how to do that...but I'd be glad too, it was a great help.

Comment: @GartuanTezMaximus Cool, thanks :) There's a checkmark you can click by the top of an answer if you consider it to have answered your question.

Comment: @BumbleB2na...not sure how I missed but anyhow thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

A solution I stumbled upon myself, that I was thinking may be useful to someone else out there as I've seen other people with similar questions...

If your clause is formatted like a sql where clause you can validate it by making a call against the database using a procedure along the lines of:

```
SET PARSE ONLY

SELECT 1
FROM sys.objects
WHERE [user generated clause]
```

If this passes with out any errors you have a valid sql where clause...

Hope this helps someone.